# worn seal between agitator spindle and drive shaft on a GE washer

Tags: washing-machine, seal, ball-bearing

10 year old washer is operating fine except for the main tub seal which is known to be leaking.

Upon disassembly, the seal/bushing around the agitator shaft appears badly worn too.  Not sure if it is leaking as well.  Is the seal designed to keep the agitator shaft centered in the squarish drive tube, or for keeping out water, or both?  Does it matter if wash water gets past that seal?

The transmission is WH38X10002.  Can't find any part number for the agitator shaft seal. I suppose I could fit a sealed ball bearing bushing in its place.

I'm wondering if the bushing screws into the inside of the squarish drive tube. Maybe the pairs of divots are for a special spanner.

Any advice?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh5XO.jpg]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

Some drive out from the bottom, once you remove the transmission, others you need a spanner wrench to remove. Look on searspartsdirect for a picture diagram using your washer model number. That should so you what the part number is and then you can check their price, and other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue- googling led me to: Appli Parts LMB 002

[https://www.amazon.com/Appli-Parts-Transmission-Lmb-002-Wh38x10002/dp/B08L74ZG9K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L74ZG9K)

$8

Answer (score 0):

That new seal will only work if you replace the bushing on the agitator shaft, otherwise the new seal will wear again in no time. Its a relatively easy fix if you know what your doing - it just takes time. The real problem is GE didn't put a groove in the bushing to allow oil to get to the top of the transmission shaft.